# BizTalk encryption

Tags: encryption, smtp, biztalk

I am developing an interface which sends an encrypted email to a partner. The partner would like the attachment only to be encrypted, with a clear-text body.

Currently, the send port encrypts both body and attachment. I did not find anything, be a property or a configuration, that would allow that.

Anybody know if this is possible in a BizTalk SMTP Send port?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible.  But you either need to do it in an Orchestration or a custom pipeline component.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I thought, but fortunately they are OK with the body and attachment encrypted.